# Setting borders around tbody, thead and tfoot with IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've designed a table in html that uses tbody, tfoot and thead. I would like to put a border-bottom and border-top on my tbody. Which works perfectly well with Firefox and Google Chrome. However Internet Explorer 8 does not display the borders at all.

After searching on the internet I haven't found any solution that did not involve some javascript; which I am not keen on using for that task.

Has anyone faced this problem before and came up with a solution that does not require javascript?

Ideally I wouldn't want to start messing around with the html too much, a solution just with css would be awesome.

Thanks for that.

Comment: Could you post the html code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try (or have set):

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```